# Не открывается ссылка при тестировании. IDEA

Tags: java, maven, test-automation

Начал осваивать автоматизирование тестирования веб. Споткнулся при первых шагах. 
Тест падает. Браузер фаерфокс (47.0.1) открывается, но по ссылке не переходит. Пробовал версию 35.0, исход тот же.

Вот maven..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ua.net.itlabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>todomvctest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

.. и код

```
package ua.net.itlabs;
import org.junit.Test;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;

public class TodoMVCTest {
    @Test
    public void testCreateTask(){

        open("http://todomvc.com/examples/troopjs_require/#/");

    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create webdriver in 15000 ms

Comment: все, проблему решил. Она крылась в версии браузера. После удаления старой и установки более ранней версии, нужно было удалить старого пользователя и добавить нового с помощью команды в командной строке firefox.exe -p